# Anonymise sensitive data in BigQuery table

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery, google-colaboratory

I have two tables in BigQuery that have the employee ID, but because those tables have sensitive information about the employees, I need to change the ID in that same table, but the same change needs to happen in both tables in order to maintain relations of data, example:

> **Table1**: Employee ID = 10000 New employee ID = 12

> **Table2**: Employee ID = 10000 New employee ID = 12

I have though about having a new table (temporary) in which having that relation between Employee ID and New employee ID, but I believe there must be a simpler solution.

I can make this change in BigQuery or even in Colab, using Python.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps [hashing](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/hash_functions) the employee ID after [appending](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#concat) a shared [salt value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) would suffice?

Comment: Hello @BobSmith thanks for your answer! I've tested FARM_FINGERPRINT() and indeed it masks the employee, maintaining the same number in all cases. However can this generate duplicate values, meaning, different employee ID be masked as the same number?

Comment: FARM_FINGERPRINT() - "Computes the fingerprint of the STRING or BYTES input using the Fingerprint64 function from the open-source FarmHash library. The output of this function for a particular input will never change." The output should be unique to every input so you should not see the same FARM_FINGERPRINT() maked output value for different employee ID inputs.

Comment: Thanks @baldwibr! Both of you were really helpfull!!